# How to find website location on a server

Tags: php, web-services, web, server-side

I have been asked to fix an issue with an website. In order to access the specific php page I need to find the location where it has been stored. I found out the IP address of the server from where it is hosted. I logged on to the server but I am unable to find the location of the files used for the website. Any suggestions how can I go about accessing the files in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Look at the web server configuration, it'll tell you.

Comment: When you say 'logged on to the server', do you mean at a command-line or via a web control panel?

Answer (score 1):

### Using command line

If your server is Apache, use comand line and search the document root in httpd.conf:

Get the path from apache

```
$ apache2 -V | grep 'SERVER_CONFIG_FILE'
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Then use grep command for getting the document root from obtained SERVER_CONFIG_FILE:

```
$ grep -i 'DocumentRoot' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

### Using php

If you want to know, what path your php script is using,  you can use:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

or

```
var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Both commands shows you full server path to your current document

Comment: You can't add code to a file before you know where the file is, and once you do, you don't need to find it any more!